# Unix Shell Script - Putting $input into file

Tags: file, shell, pipe

I need to put $input into the file spelled.. but this code leaves the file empty. I am only correcting the first word that comes up in the array, so i'm thinking that when I just hit 'Enter' that it is rewriting the file over? any help?

```
# store words in file
cat $1 | ispell -l > file
# move words in file into array
array=($(< file))
# remove temp file
rm file
# print out words & ask for corrections
for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ ))
do
        read -p "' ${array[i]} ' is mispelled. Press "Enter" to keep
this spelling, or type a correction here: " input
echo $input > spelled
done
# show corrections
cat spelled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>>` instead of `>` if you want to append when the file exists.

```
echo $input >> spelled
```